# Grails dbCreate property value "create-drop" not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, grails, integration-testing

I have defined my data source for environment `test` as:

```
test {

    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;"
    }
}
```

But when trying to run my tests next time the data from previous test doesn't seem to be removed.

Comment: How do you run the tests? Which Grails version are you working? Keep in mind that in newer Grails version there is a Daemon running in the background.

Comment: @saw303 I do `grails -integration test-app` to run my tests. I'm on Grails 2.3.11. What are the implications of the Grails Daemon? Thanks

Comment: `grails test run-app // runs with the test data source`